# Wrap text around a whole circle as path

Tags: gimp, text-wrap, text-on-path

I want to take some text and have it wrap around the edge of a circle, with the top of the letters toward the center of the circle. Using a pair of tutorials ([curve text](https://itsfoss.com/curve-text-gimp/), [circle with text](https://daviesmediadesign.com/wrap-text-around-a-circle-in-gimp-2-10/)), I have gotten text to do this. However, there is a weird bug in how it calculates text wrapping; it uses only about 3/4 of the circle before wrapping to a second line. The two minimal-difference examples are below; one uses 169 pt font and the other 170 pt.

Ideally, this text would wrap around the entire circle, with only slightly more room between the end and the beginning than between words. I expected that by slowly adjusting the size, this could be accomplished, but it jumps suddenly. What is going on, and how can I fix it?

[image: premature stopping]

[image: premature wrapping]

Comment: Don't use GIMP for this. It's much easier in vector software.  Inkscape is free and open source. Use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Set the text box that is being wrapped to the path to be dynamic, in the tool options. For some reason this setting is respected even when the text is being placed on a path, so it was wrapping to the length of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the text around the entire circle by two ways:

1st : By changing the text size to greater value so it wraps completely but the uper portion text would look upside down.

2nd and clean option : By manually creating a circle and pasting the text that goes in the bottom line (by Type > Type on a Path > Flip) and creating another circle which goes in the centre of the first circle and then Type on a path but this time you don't have to flip the text and write the other half of the text. Now match the sizes of uper and lower text to form a circle.

You're done!!

I hope this will help you :))